# Show that $ \prod_{k=1}^{n}a_{k, \sigma(k)} = \prod_{k=1}^{n}a_{\sigma^{-1}(k), k}$ on any matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

At some point, in proving that $\det{A} = \det{A^T}$, one states that

\begin{align*}
\prod_{k=1}^{n}a_{k, \sigma(k)} = \prod_{k=1}^{n}a_{\sigma^{-1}(k), k}
\end{align*}

Why is this true?

Comment: This is just a relabeling of indices / reordering of the product.

Comment: You should make a point of calling $\sigma$ a permutation (of the indices) in your Question.  Even when notation has a conventional meaning, the details can be crucial to understanding the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let start by fixing some notations. Let $n \in \Bbb{N}$, $X = \{i \in \Bbb{N} \colon i \leq n\}$, $\sigma \in S_n$ and $A \in \cal{M}_{n}(\Bbb{K})$. Now, consider the two products that you mention

\begin{align*}
A = \prod_{k=1}^n a_{k \, \sigma{(k)}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad B = \prod_{k=1}^{n} a_{\sigma^{-1}(k) \, k}.
\end{align*}

Let us prove that $A = B$.

Let $i \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $i \leq n$. We clearly have that $(i,\sigma(i)) \in X^2$. Since $\sigma$ is a permutation of $X$, we know that $\sigma$ is a bijective application of $X$ to $X$. Hence, it exists $\sigma^{-1} \in S_n$. Since $\sigma{(i)} \in X$, then it exists a unique (because $\sigma$ is bijective) $j \in X$ such that $j= \sigma(i)$ and $\sigma^{-1}(j) = i$. So for all $i \in X$, it exists a unique $j \in X$ such that $i = \sigma^{-1}(j)$ and $\sigma(i) = j$. Therefore, by making this substitution, and reordering the elements in the product (because multiplication is commutative), we conclude that $A = B$.

In short, it all comes from the fact that $\sigma$ is bijective and therefore we can associate those pairs $(i,\sigma(i))$ to $(\sigma^{-j},j)$ is a unique way such that, by reordering the elements in the product, we obtain the same result. (Nothing changes, it is just a substitution)

Answer (score 0):

Write $N=\{1,\dots,n\}$.
Index substitution $j=\sigma(k)$ (same as $k=\sigma^{-1}(j)$ inclusive $\sigma(N)=N$ because $\sigma$ bijection) yields
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n a_{k\sigma(k)}
=
\prod_{k\in N} a_{k\sigma(k)}
=
\prod_{j\in\sigma(N)} a_{\sigma^{-1}(j)j}
=
\prod_{j=1}^n a_{\sigma^{-1}(j)j}
.
$$